# Get column values from the selected rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

When using [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net) how do I get column values for the rows returned by fnGetNodes? I'm  using the function below that returns the selected rows. I want to use the return value of this function to delete the selected rows from the database. However, to do that I need the uniqueid value of each selected row. One other potential problem is that the uniqueid attr is marked with:

> bVisible: false

so that it isn't actually displayed to the user as it is of no interest to them.

```
/* Get the rows that are selected */
function fnGetSelected( oTableLocal )
{
    var aReturn = new Array();
    var aTrs = oTableLocal.fnGetNodes();

    for ( var i=0 ; i<aTrs.length ; i++ )                                       
    {
        if ( $(aTrs[i]).hasClass('row_selected') )
        {
            aReturn.push( aTrs[i] );
        }
    }
    return aReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the fnGetData() method for DataTable. If you pass the selected row it will return an array of the row that you want.

Comment: Thanks swisstony. Good luck!!